# Is there a way to format the output of Select-String to include newlines between the results?

Tags: powershell, grep

Is there a way to format the output of Select-String to include newlines between the results without resorting to writing a custom program?

Current behavior:

```
PS D:\StackOverflowSelectStringSpacingQuestion> Get-ChildItem . | Select-String a

a.txt:1:a
a.txt:2:a
a.txt:3:a
```

Desired behavior:

```
PS D:\StackOverflowSelectStringSpacingQuestion> Get-ChildItem . | Select-String a

a.txt:1:a

a.txt:2:a

a.txt:3:a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a pithier way than this, but it works:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Select-String a | Out-String -Stream | Foreach {"$_`n"}
```